# How can I refresh the page when the submit button of a form is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

For example I have this code:

```
<form name="formm" action="http://example.com/" target="_blank">
    <input type="text" name="txt" />
    <input type="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

When I click submit it sends the form to the link which opens in a new tab. This is exactly what I want to happen. However, I would also like my page to refresh so I can run some PHP code. Simple enough, I add this to my submit input:

```
onclick="location.reload()"
```

This seems to work in any other case except when it's added to the submit button. How can I get this to work?

Comment: Just set action to empty. <form action="" />

Comment: Can't leave the action empty because I'm sending the data to another page (search query).

Answer (score 2):

Within the form that is submitting to a new page, add `onClick="reloadpage();"`. This works in all 5 browsers:

```
function reloadpage()
{

    var returnURL = "this_pages_name.php?upd=" + Math.random() * 100;

    setTimeout(function() 
    {
        window.location=returnURL; 
    }, 50 );


}
```

Comment: - Chrome Version 48.0.2564.116
- IE 11
- Safari 5.1.7
- Firefox 43.0.1
- Opera 12.7

But there isn't too much here. Basically just a JS setTimeout function delaying the reload of the page, and that's been around forever. Trisan's use of "reload" will work too. I just have a series of parameters I also needed to send back, plus included the Math.random() so there's no way a cached version would be shown. You can certainly do it the way he mentioned. This is just the way I did it.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
onsubmit="setTimeout(function () { window.location.reload(); }, 10)"
```

I use this for my forms and it works perfectly across all browsers :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try;

```
$('#form_id').on("submit", function() {

  location.reload();

});
```

This shouldn't prevent the default action of the form being submitted, but should capture the event and reload the page.

You will need to specify an ID on the form.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP before generating any output declare a header to move location to current file:

```
header('Location: .');
```

This will set header location to: '.' (current directory) and then look for your page again. It will also clear any form datasets preventing database spam